# Error C2439: member could not be initialized

Tags: c++, templates

I get compiler errors in :

```
template<class _Other1,
        class _Other2>
        _Pair_base(_Other1&& _Val1, _Other2&& _Val2)
        : first(_STD forward<_Other1>(_Val1)),
            second(_STD forward<_Other2>(_Val2))
        {   
        }

    _Ty1 first; 
    _Ty2 second;    
    };

error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'const PP_PropertyType 
error C2439: 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::second' : member could not be initialized
```

I'm not sure if this part of code is enough... Do you have any suggestion what should I do?

Thanks for any help

Comment: No, you're not getting compiler errors inside standard library. And the error even says what's wrong and where (if you'd read more, you'd notice how there's a pointer to your code where the template is used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to initialize something like this:

```
pair<SomeType, PP_PropertyType> x(foo, 1234);
```

and it cant convert the second parameter (1234) from an int to a PP_PropertyType.

The problem shows up in a standard library error in the base class of std::pair, but it is caused in your code.